# how to config webpack to output umd/esm/system at one time?

Tags: webpack

Seems that webpack got only one output object and one library config (rollup support multi output), I can only get one library target working like:

```
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
    library: {
      name: {
        root: "MyLibrary",
        amd: "my-library",
        commonjs: "my-common-library",
      },
      type: "umd",
    },
  },
```

How to support mulit output in one config?

Answer (score 2):

You can export an array from `webpack.config.js`: one entry per config. You setup esm/umd/cjs... in each.

```
module.exports = [
  {
    output: {...},
    ...commonConfig 
  },
    {
    output: {...},
    ...commonConfig 
  },
  ...
]
```